# Using SQL Wildcards with LINQ

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, wildcard

I have a question about using LINQ to access a Database and trying to make use of it's version of accessing the `LIKE` comparison operator.

I know that LINQ has `.Contains()`, `.StartsWith()`, and `.EndsWith()` as comparison methods.  However I am wondering if there is a way to programatically imcorporate SQL Wildcards into a LINQ statement without explicitly using these query operators.  Let me explain my situation.

I am writing a program that accesses a database, and part of the program is a search window which the user can use to help them find specific database data.  I would like to *try* and incorporate SQL Wildcards into the textbox fields for these search pages.

For example if a user enters the input `17%` I'd want the program to check for anything in that specific column that starts with a `17`.  The same is true with `%17` and `17` where I'd want it to search for columns that end with, and contain the values.

Currently, this is the code I have for my search method:

```
Public Function Data_Search(sData As List(Of String), DB As CustomDataContext) As DataGridView
    Dim gridData As New DataGridView
    Dim query = From p In DB.Parts
                Select p.Part_Number, p.Part_Description, p.Supplier.Supplier_Name
    for i = 0 To sData.Count - 1
        If Not sData(i).ToString() = "" Then
            Select Case i
                Case 0
                    Dim partNum As String = sData(i).ToString()
                    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.Part_Number.Contains(partNum))
                Case 1
                    Dim description As String = sData(i).ToString()
                    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.Part_Description.Contains(description))
                Case 2
                    Dim supp As String = sData(i).ToString()
                    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.Supplier_Name.Contains(supp))
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    gridData.DataSource = query.ToList()
    Return gridData
End Function
```

So right now I am trying to see if there is a way for me to modify the code in a way that doesn't essentially involve me putting a substring search into each `Case` section to determine if I should be using `StartsWith()`, `Contains()`, or `EndsWith`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe LinqKit could help? http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: @Tim I am programming this in VB.Net, and it seems like LinqKit is a C# extension.

Comment: The .NET languages are compatible - if it has what you need you could probably load it in your project and translate the samples. I've had to do similar things moving back and forth across languages.

Comment: LINQ is too broad, what ORM are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev SQLServer.  Sorry.

Comment: Not database mate, the ORM (framework you use to query the database) - e.g. EF6, EF Core etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev Honestly....I am not sure.  I put this database together using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, and for LINQ I used to item you can Select from the Data Section of 'Add New Item' in Visual Studio.  I'm honestly pretty new with working with this stuff so I don't know how to find specifically what you're asking me about.

Comment: That sounds like you are using LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LINQ to SQL, and you are talking to Microsoft SQL Server, then you can use `SQLMethods.Like` to implement SQL `LIKE`:

```
query = query.Where(Function(x) SQLMethods.Like(x.Part_Number, partNum))
```